# Capturing Network calls using chrome browser but getting NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, selenium

Below is the code used to capture network calls using chrome browser, but this throws as error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");


    BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);

    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.merge(capabilities);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    // enable more detailed HAR capture, if desired (see CaptureType for the complete list)
    proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

    // create a new HAR with the label "yahoo.com"
    proxy.newHar("yahoo.com");

    // open yahoo.com
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");

    // get the HAR data
    Har har = proxy.getHar();
}
```

Comment: wrong version of guava. it's nothing to do with the source code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Guava to 21.0 or later.

Comment: this should be comment.